# tableau-react problem to show up full screen mode icon in tableau server or tableau public

Tags: reactjs, tableau-api

I have a problem to show full screen icon from tableau server or tableau public.

Actually, I used React for my front-end and plugin tableau-react to embed tableau URL from tableau server or tableau public.

Here is my code review

```
const options = {
                hideTabs: true,
                width: '100%',
                height: 1000,
                allowFullScreen: true
            };

const urlTableau  = 'http://public.tableau.com/views/CottonwoodPassAreaMap/WayPointsbetweenCottonwoodpassandCrabtreeMeadows?:embed=y&:display_count=yes';
this.setState({
    iframeTableau: <TableauReport
                    url={urlTableau}
                    options={options}
                   />
            });
```

Is there any problem with my code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The tableau-react documentation says that the supported props for options are:

```
const options = {
  height: 100,
  width: 100,
  hideTabs: false,
  // All other vizCreate options are supported here, too
  // They are listed here: https://help.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api_ref.htm#vizcreateoptions_record
};
```

I can't see the `allowFullScreen` option anywhere on the [VizCreateOptions Record](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api_ref.htm#vizcreateoptions_record) , so I assume you would need to create a separate iframe that contains the TableauReport component, and then make the iframe fullscreen.